# How to remove empty lines in bash when they are enclosed by one or several semicolon and quotes

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Let me explain my issue.

- Bash version 4.2.1 over Red Hat Linux version 7

I have a set of CSV files that are coming with different number of columns, all values enclosed on quotes. What I don't know in advance is the number of columns , neither the number of semicolons. What I do know is that an empty line has always as many semicolons as number of columns in the csv minus 1.
The pattern that can be repeated is "";"" for each column in the csv.

So I could have a file like this

```
col1;col2;col3 
"value1";"value2";"value3"
"";"";""
```

Or I could have a file like this

```
col1;col2;col3;col4;col5;col6;
"value1";"value2";"value3";"value4";"value5";"value6"
"";"";"";"";"";""
```

**Update**

Or I could have a file like this

```
col1;col2;col3;col4;col5;col6;
"value1";"value2";"value3";"value4";"value5";"value6"
"";"";"";"";"";""
"";"";"value3";"value4";"";""
```

My issue is that I need to eliminate the lines where only semicolons appear without values, but I don't know in advance how many semicolons. This part should be integrated in a shell script that does a lot of things with these csv files.

Does any know how to do this in a standard way ? with awk perhaps or using regular expressions ?

My current way ( which is nonsense ) looks for the number of columns , to then check how many semicolons can appear, based on that I build the  pattern.

```
 # how many columns in the csv
 num_columns=$(awk -F';' '{print NF; exit}' file.csv)
 # pattern is for value - 1
 num_pattern=$(expr $num_columns - 1)

 # case $num_pattern 
   in 
     1)  
        pattern="\"\";\"\""
        ;;
     2) 
        pattern="\"\";\"\";\"\""
        ;;
     ## so on so forth up to xx columns
   esac
```

I could use this, because I know that the maximum number of columns for any of the incoming csv files is 12. But I guess there might be a better way to do this.

```
$ pattern="\"\";\"\""
$ echo $pattern
"";""
$ cat file.csv | tail -n+2 | egrep $pattern
"";""
"";""
"";""
"";""
"";""
"";""
"";""
"";""
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grep and a regex. The command below will match all lines of the files that have one or more `"";` and that ends with `""`:

```sh
grep -E '^("";)+""$' file.csv
```

If you want to invert the match (*i.e.* only have the lines that do not match), add the `-v` flag to the command above, for example:

```sh
grep -v -E '^("";)+""$' file.csv > newfile.csv
```

Comment: fantastic!! just what I wanted . Many many thanks ;)

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer to close the question ;)

Comment: I am waiting for the mandatory 2 minutes, to accept the answer ;)

Comment: The regular expression `("";)+""` in `grep` will also match the line `x;"";""`, which I doubt the OP wants that. Additionally, see [Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: @M.NejatAydin, I incorporated your comments in my answer, thanks

Comment: @qmeeus, what happens if the pattern also appears in a line that contains also other characters ? I updated the question, to provide a third example, because the current grep expression also removes lines where values are mixed with the pattern

Comment: I changed the pattern yesterday to force the entire line to match (by including `^$` symbols). This was to address the issue raised in the comments above. When I apply this new pattern to the example in your updated answer, it succeeds and only removes "empty" lines, leaving the ones where at least one field contains data